# android RelativeLayout

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, android-relativelayout

is it possible to use RelativeLayout to have one area on top, which uses all available space (wich should be filled some Views dynamically) and to Buttons which should be on the lower end of the screen?

I tried following, but with no effort:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/topFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="blabla"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:text="Button 1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/topFrame"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="6dp" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button2" 
    android:text="Button 2" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="6dp" />
```

whith this solution the button fills the space and not the FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

TRy this:

```
<RelativeLayout......>
<FrameLayout 
android:id="@+id/topFrame"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_margin="6dp">

<TextView
    android:text="blabla"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</FrameLayout>  
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button 
       .....
    </Button>

    <Button 
       .....
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the FrameLayout, change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` then include `android:layout_above="@+id/button1"`.  It should force the force the FrameLayout to fill the space and always be above the first button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:text="Button" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/button2" 
android:text="Button" 
android:layout_above="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" 
android:layout_above="@+id/button2" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="TextView"         
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/textView1">
</TextView>


</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry if I missed something.